# Select rows where all in a group are not null postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `groups(group_id)`, `member(group_id, name)` and I would like to select all the `members` in groups where *everyone* in the group has a non-null name. For example, if this is the `members` table:

```
group_id|name
1|a
1|b
2|c
2|null
3|null
3|null
```

then the result of the query should return:

```
group_id|name
1|a
1|b
```

I tried running

```
SELECT * FROM members M1 
WHERE ALL(SELECT M2.name IS NOT NULL FROM members M2)
ORDER BY M1.group_id
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm confused. The query you're showing shows that both tables are the same.

Comment: @CoryMadden I'm not sure what you mean. I didn't write the groups table for the sake of brevity. The second table is what the result of the query should be

Comment: I mean the code block with your SELECT statement shows that M1 and M2 are both the same table. So I don't understand why you're giving them aliases when you could just do `SELECT * FROM members WHERE name IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @CoryMadden Yes, M1 and M2 are the same table. What's the problem?

Comment: I updated my comment.

Comment: @CoryMadden because I don't want anyone from groups like group 2 where anyone in the group has a null name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`bool_and()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select group_id, name
from members
where group_id in (
    select group_id
    from members
    group by 1
    having bool_and(name is not null)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM groups g
INNER JOIN members m
ON g.group_id = m.group_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM members mbr WHERE mbr.name IS NULL AND mbr.group_id = m.group_id)
```

Essentially, we select all records, except for those where we can find a null name record with the same group ID.

Note that I don't believe this is SARG-able, so if you have a massive database that relies on indexes, this may be a bit on the slow side.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to group and display non null value, how if just a simple

```
SELECT group_id, name FROM members 
group by group_id, name
having name is not null and id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE group_id NOT IN (
   SELECT group_id FROM table
   WHERE name IS NULL
)
```